# Construct a smooth function in a certain pattern.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If we were given a sequence of positive numbers {a_n}, can we construct a smooth function(can be derivatived for infinitely many times) that has nth derivatives at 0 that is bigger than the given number a_n?
I believe it's right, but I cannot construct one to convince others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Borel's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63050/every-power-series-is-the-taylor-series-of-some-c-infty-function) theorem gives more: you can choose the value at $0$. Moreover, we can choose the values of the derivatives [on a set which consitst of isolated points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66459/about-borels-lemma/66460#66460).