# Does Taylor series always converge somewhere to some function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, smooth-functions

Suppose $f$ is $C^\infty$ on an open set $U$, and $x \in U$. Does $Tf$, the Taylor series centered at $x$, converge in a neighborhood of $x$ to some function(not necessarily the original function $f$)? To be more precise, if $B$ is an open ball centered at $x$ contained in $U$, do we have $Tf$ converges in $B$?

I’m not asking about Taylor series not equal to the original function. It’s a totally different question.

Comment: If by "smooth" you mean analytic, then yes; the power series has positive radius of convergence equal to distance of $x$ to the nearest singularity.  But if smooth just means infinitely differentiable, then the answer is no.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8273506?noredirect=1 does not answer my question. It just give an example not a proof

Comment: That example’s Taylor series converge, but is it true for all smooth function? If yes, I need a proof

Comment: I have voted to reopen.  Note that I'm not the one who voted to close as duplicate.  My Comment initially was asking you to clarify your Question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will clarify my question

Comment: The answer for my second question is no. Consider $\frac{1}{1-x}$, which is real analytic except at $1$. Modify this function near $x=1$ to be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then the Taylor series of new function centered at $0$ still only converges on $|x| <1$ rather than converges on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, such functions exist. Take a power series centered at $0$ such that its radius of convergence is $0$, such as, say,$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^nx^n.\tag1$$Then, according to [Borel's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66459/446262), there is a smooth function $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):f^{(n)}(0)=n!n^n.$$So, the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $0$ is the power series $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This answers my question!

Comment: I am sorry for having closed it as a duplicate the first time I saw it. I misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: That’s fine. That helps me clarifying my questions and rethink about them.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t know the accept function of this app